# How to get collection in a lodash chain?

Tags: javascript, lodash, chain

I am currently using lodash with chain. I did something like that :

```
let result = _(myCollection)
    .filter(...)
    .map(...)
    .value()
return _.reduce(result, (a, b) => a && b, result.length != 0)
```

But I am not happy with that. I would like to do all in one instruction in order to obtain something like that :

```
return _(myCollection)
    .filter(...)
    .map(...)
    .reduce((a, b) => a && b, myMappedCollection.length != 0)
    .value()
```

I can't find a way to get back my collection currently processed. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: isnt that the 4th param of reduce? and then a&&b&&arr.length, or natively: .every(e=>e)

Comment: Unfortunately the documentation motions only 3 parameters. I will do a quick test to verify that. Here is the documentation : https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#reduce

Comment: the native .reduce does so. not shure about lodash

Comment: but it looks like *iteratee is invoked with four arguments:
(accumulator, value, index|key, collection).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in the documentation: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#reduce

> Reduces collection to a value which is the accumulated result of running each element in collection thru iteratee, where each successive invocation is supplied the return value of the previous. If accumulator is not given, the first element of collection is used as the initial value. The iteratee is invoked with four arguments:
>   **(accumulator, value, index|key, collection).**

You could do the following

```
return _(myCollection)
.filter(...)
.map(...)
.reduce((a, b, indx, myMappedCollection) => a && b, myMappedCollection.length != 0)
.value()
```